# Working out number of years in compound interest using python function

Tags: python-3.x, function, math

School Question:

Build a function `retirement_age(PMT, i, FV, start_age)` that calculates the (whole) `age` at which your customer can retire, if they:

- Invest an amount, `PMT` at the END of every YEAR (with the first
  payment made exactly one year from now),
- at an interest rate of `i%` per year, compounded annually.
- They require an amount of AT LEAST `FV` in order to be able to afford
  retirement.
- They just turned `start_age` years old.

I am struggling to solve the number of years `PMT` would take to reach `FV`

This is my code:

```
def retirement_age(PMT, i, FV, start_age):
count = 0

while PMT <= FV: #PMT set to loop till it reaches FV
    PMT = PMT * (1+i)
    count = count + 1 #adds 1 to count value until while loop satisfied
    age = count + start_age #adds count value to start_age to determine retirement age
return int(age) #returns age

print (retirement_age(20000, 0.1, 635339.63, 20))
```

my answer with this code:

```
57
```

The answer is supposed to be:

```
35
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. And the task specifically mentions that we are not allowed to import external functions like `math` for example, which means I can't use `math.log()` which would probably solve all my problems.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but the `<=` should probably just be a `<`. The loop only needs to continue while they have too little, not when the amount equals FV

Comment: I see, thank you for the input

Comment: And this code doesn't seem to take into account what's newly invested each year. It just compounds the existing principle. Shouldn't that be something like `PMT = PMT + (PMT * (i + 1))`? Or something like that. You need to add new PMT each year.

Comment: Yeah I did try that, then I got an answer of 25 instead

Comment: Well, I would make that change then work from there. That's at least closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll note that broad debugging questions like this aren't very appropriate for SO.

Having said that, I played around with it and after reading the specs again, I found the issue(s). I figured I might as well post it.

- You only need to keep calculating while the principal is *less* than the future value. You can stop once they're equal.
- The main issues however were that you aren't adding any money each year. You're just accumulating interest on the initial principal. And...
- You invested `PMT` immediately. The investment doesn't happen until the *end* of the year, as the instructions emphasize. That means at the start of the looping, he has 0 invested. That means he doesn't start accumulating interest until the start of the second loop/year.

---

```
def retirement_age(PMT, i, FV, start_age):
    age = start_age
    p = 0

    while p < FV:
        p = PMT + p * (1+i)
        age += 1

    return int(age)

print(retirement_age(20000, 0.1, 635339.63, 20))
# 35
```

I introduced `p` to keep track of the running balance since it's separate from what's being added each year. Your logic for keeping track of age was also a little convoluted, so I simplified it down a bit.

Comment: I see what you did there, in order for my equation to equal 20000 in the first year there has to be a variable set to 0 so that it cancels out the rest of the equation and only keep `PMT` for the initial year, but grows as the loop continues. And thanks for simplifying my `age`, That looks much better. Let me try it on python quickly. I will revert back, it should work though.

Comment: @MengeziDhlomo I'm not sure what you mean by "cancelling". `p` is the amount of money invested. It's zero the first year, and accumulates zero interest until PMT is added to it at the end of the first year. `p` and `PMT` are distinct variables in the equation.

Comment: No, no. I understand it perfectly. Not to worry. I think it's just how my comment is worded which makes it a little confusing. The code works perfectly. Will obviously have to change a few things to avoid some sort of plagiarism offense. Thanks again. I will mark this as correct

Comment: @MengeziDhlomo Fix your variable names. Caps should only be used for class names. All the names should be in lowercase. The int cast for the return is also redundant if toy can guarantee the input age will be an integer, which seems to be the case.